# Mail sent with mail() function does not get sent

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php mail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757113/php-mail-function)

I am doing this website where I send emails to users when they for example forget their password or similar, but for some reason I can not send emails with the following function:

```
$email = 'somemail@mail.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'message blablablablabla';


mail($email, $subject, $message);
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something in the code, or is it the hosting company's fault? (I make my website on x10hosting.com). I checked in the manual about mail() but it didn't help me. 
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thanks for the help guys, but it turned out to be a problem on the web hosting company I'm on. Everything's working fine now.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757113/php-mail-function for better usage.

Answer (score 1):

try to use with headers`enter code here`

```
     $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$frommail.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$frommail."\r\n";
$mail_sent=mail($tomail,  $msg, $headers);`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess either there is no `sendmail_from` value set in `php.ini` or your host does not support email or has not set it up correctly.

Try setting a from header, and if that doesn't work, contact your host:

`mail($email, $subject, $message,'From: you@example.com');`

Answer (score 1):

is this on local host? or is it on a webserver

Also remember that mail($to, $subject, $contents) returns a boolean,

```
  if(mail($to, $subject, $body){
       echo "Message has been sent";
  }
  else{
       echo "Error has occurred"
  }
```

Comment: It says: "message has been sent", but I still don't get anything neither on Gmail nor on hotmail. But thanks for the help.

Comment: I recently have worked on this, and i did notice a delay.. And if its a gmail account it shows as Unprivileged user.. Have you checked your spam folder? maybe it redirected it there.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the spam folder. BTW, how long was the delay for you?

Comment: was between 1-10 minutes, sometimes it was instant. just depended on my connection that day since I was running it locally